# Unable to select currency in a dropdown

Tags: javascript, dropdown

I have a dropdown where i can choose currency, how can i choose for Example EUR in the dropdown using js?

[Dropdown code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTCPG.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dont post the code as image.. instead use the in-built code blocker

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

Get the select element:

```
const select_element = document.querySelector('select[name="curr_pay"]')
```

Select the option with the value attribute equal to 'EUR'

```
select_element.value = 'EUR'
```

You can visit this page at [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_value.asp) for more information.

Comment: auth – "success" but the currency hasn't changed

Comment: should i somehow set a variable first? select_element

Comment: select_element is a variable containing the element. I used document.querySelector to get it. You can also use for example document.getElementById or if you're using jQuery, you can use $('select[name="curr_pay"]')[0].

Comment: I tried, there is no ID, unfortunately

Comment: The solution is - document.querySelector('option[value=" + value +"]').selected = true